# Confusion on the Chain rule on the partial derivative and related notation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have a HW problem:

Define
$$f(x,y_1,y_2) = (y_1^3+y_2^3-3y_1y_2,xy_1-y_2)$$
and $V = \mathbb{R} \setminus\{-1\}$. Let $\phi:V \to \mathbb{R}^2$ and 
$$\phi(x) = \frac{3x}{x^3+1}(1,x)\in \mathbb{R}^2$$
I have already proved that 
$$f(x,\phi(x)) = 0$$
for all $x \in V$. However, it then asks this:

*Determine the set of* $x \in V$ *for which*
$$det\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial(y_1,y_2)}(x,\phi(x))\right) \neq 0$$
I am struggling what this notation really stands for and how to apply the Chain rule on it. (I always get a vector which can't compute its determinant)

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial(y_1,y_2)}(x,\phi(x))$ is shorthand for the following $2 \times 2$ matrix of real numbers:
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y_1}(x,\phi(x)) & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y_2}(x,\phi(x)) \\
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y_1}(x,\phi(x)) & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y_2}(x,\phi(x))
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
where $f_i$ means the $i^{th}$ component function of $f$. (You need to be careful about what is the actual function you're differentiating, and **where you are evaluating the derivative**.)

---

**Edit To Clarify the notation and computation:**

For example, $f_2(x,y_1,y_2) = xy_1-y_2$. So, let's compute the following partial derivative:
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial y_1}(x,y_1,y_2) = x
\end{align}
This says we're evaluating the partial derivative $\dfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial y_1}$ at the point $(x,y_1,y_2)$, and the answer we get is $x$. Therefore, if we evaluate at $(x, \phi(x))$, we get
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial y_1}(x,\phi(x)) = x
\end{align}

In this special case, the answer turned out to be the same regardless of where we evaluated, but this is just a lucky coincidence that $\dfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial y_1}$ depends only on the first entry.

Comment: Thanks for the editing and the answer! Then how can I take the chain rule of it? Since there is no $\partial \phi(x)/\partial y_1$ such a thing.

Comment: @UnbelieveTable You don't. You do the partial derivatives first, then evaluate the resulting matrix at the point $(x, \phi(x))$.

Comment: @UnbelieveTable There is no chain rule involved. This was the purpose of my parenthetical remark. You're first computing the partial derivatives of $f$, and only afterwards evaluating them at the point $(x,\phi(x)) \in \Bbb{R}$

Comment: @eyeballfrog Wait, so you are saying that the chain rule is not required? Why is that? Isn't it like a composition?

Comment: @peek-a-boo Okay, so you mean the notation is exactly the matrix that you wrote.

Comment: @UnbelieveTable Yes, the notation is just a short way of writing the $2 \times 2$ matrix I wrote. I now edited my answer to include a sample computation of one of the matrix entries.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks for your work! Now I know what to do.